# android undo flag FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Tags: android, android-activity, keyguard

I added a flag to an activity

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

is there a way to undo this without recreating activity? I need to do this whan a state changes in my application.

Answer (score 2):

found it

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```